# Auto hide and show div after 2 seconds

Tags: timeout, hide, show, intervals

I am very new to these kinds of scripts and would be very thankful for any help.

I have 3 rotating divs and want div1 to show for 2 seconds, then div2 to show for 2 seconds, then div3 to show for 2 seconds and then the whole cycle to start from the beginning. One div at a time while the other 2 are hidden. I'd also like to get rid of the click to start the function but as soon as I visit the page the cycle to begin.

I am basically taking the code from the following post. I got all that to work
[auto hide div after 2 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174750/auto-hide-div-after-2-seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery `.fadein()` and `.fadeout()` or `.css('display','none')` and use `window.setInterval(FunctionName, 2000);`

Every two seconds the function you enter in the first parameter will run. Create a variable that keeps track of which div you're about to show. When the variable goes to 3 you reset it to 1 so the process can continue infinitely.

Edit:

style:

```
div{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    margin-left:50px;
    border:1 px solid black;
    float:left;
    opacity:0;
}
#div3
{
    opacity:1;
}

div:nth-child(odd){
    background:#dad;
}
div:nth-child(even){
    background:#a55;
}
```

jquery/js:

```
var Index = 1;

window.setInterval(ChangeVisibleDiv, 2000);

function ChangeVisibleDiv()
{
    var nextIndex = Index + 1;
    var prevIndex = Index - 1;
    //reset on 4, not 3 because then the 3rd div would never be faded out.
    if(Index == 4)
        nextIndex = 1;
    // opposite story here as above
    if(Index == 1)
        prevIndex = 3;

     $(("#div" + prevIndex)).css('opacity',0);
     $(("#div" + nextIndex)).css('opacity',0);
     $(("#div" + Index)).css('opacity',1);

    Index++;

    //reset on 4, not 3 because then the 3rd div would never be faded out.
    if(Index == 4)
        Index = 1;

}
```

html

```
<div id="div1">

</div>
<div id="div2">

</div>
<div id="div3">

</div>
```

It starts at the third div, I hope you don't mind because I'm too lazy to fix =)

I really recommend you learn some jquery and javascript, though. It's not clever to use something if you dont know how it works. At least learn the fundamentals.

Also, people on this forum want questions that are fun and challenging, not assignments from school =)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. While I understand what these do I'm sorry to say that I don't know how to use them.
How could that look in the code then?

Comment: god damnit jlen! im lazy. lol, ok I'll be back in 15 minutes I hope.